# Como retornar um objeto usando o nome do objeto como parâmetro da função?

Tags: javascript, funções, objetos

boa noite!

Alguém consegue me dizer como posso retornar o objeto usando uma invocação do tipo:

book(livro1);

```
function book(bookName) {
      var obj = {
        livro1: {
          quantidadePaginas: 300,
          autor: "Jorge",
          editora: "Atlas"
        },
        livro2: {
          quantidadePaginas: 200,
          autor: "Paulo",
          editora: "Cia dos Livros"
        },
        livro3: {
          quantidadePaginas: 150,
          autor: "Pedro",
          editora: "Bartolomeu"
        }
      };
      if (!bookName) {
        return obj;
      };
      return obj.bookName;
    };
```

Quando tento retornar dessa forma, aparece que o livro1 não está definido.

Onde meu pensamento está errado?

O que eu preciso alterar na função para que eu possa retornar o valor do objeto x (livrox) usando a invocação book(livrox)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando `obj.bookName` você está tentando acessar a propriedade `bookName` de `obj`, que não existe e por isso retorna undefined.

Você precisa, em vez disso, usar `obj[bookName]`. Assim, ele vai tentar acessar a propriedade cujo nome é igual ao valor armazenado na variável `bookName`.

Veja mais sobre isso aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos

Comment: Mesmo substituindo return obj.bookName por return obj[bookName], e invocando book(livro1); continua dizendo que livro1 não está definido...

Answer (score 2):

Como [luislhl](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/15554/luislhl) disse para acessar a propriedade cujo o valor vem na variável passada como argumento você vai precisar usar `obj[bookName]`, mas também lembre de passar uma string na chamada da função `book("livro1")`. Se você chamar apenas usando `book(livro1)` o interpretador vai esperar que `livro1` seja uma variável previamente declarada.

```
var livro1 = "livro1"
book(livro1)
```

Se você não declarar a variável ou não passar como string o erro `Uncaught ReferenceError: livro1 is not defined` será disparado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método `eval()` para converter o parâmetro `bookName`, mas chame a função com 'livro1' entre aspas:

```js
    function book(bookName) {
     
     var obj = {
      livro1: {
       quantidadePaginas: 300,
       autor: "Jorge",
       editora: "Atlas"
      },
      livro2: {
       quantidadePaginas: 200,
       autor: "Paulo",
       editora: "Cia dos Livros"
      },
      livro3: {
       quantidadePaginas: 150,
       autor: "Pedro",
       editora: "Bartolomeu"
      }
     };
     if (!bookName) {
      return obj;
     };
     return eval('obj.'+bookName);
    };
    
    console.log(book('livro1'));
```